# How to handle more than one SIGSEGV occurrence in linux?

Tags: linux, memory-management, kernel, segmentation-fault

I have written a program to scan kernel memory for a pattern from user space.  I run it from root.  I expect that it will generate SIGSEGVs when it hits pages that aren't accessible; I would like to ignore those faults and just jump to the next page to continue the search.  I have set up a signal handler that works fine for the first occurrence, and it continues onward as expected.  However, when a second SIGSEGV occurs, the handler is ignored (it was reregistered after the first occurrence) and the program terminates.  The relevant portions of the code are:

```
jmp_buf restore_point;
void segv_handler(int sig, siginfo_t* info, void* ucontext)
{
    longjmp(restore_point, SIGSEGV);
}
void setup_segv_handler()
{
  struct sigaction sa;
  sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO|SA_RESTART|SA_RESETHAND;
  sigemptyset (&sa.sa_mask);
  sa.sa_sigaction = &segv_handler;
  if (sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to setup SIGSEGV handler\n");
  }
}
unsigned long search_kernel_memory_area(unsigned long start_address, size_t area_len, const void* pattern, size_t pattern_len)
{
    int fd;
    char* kernel_mem;

    fd = open("/dev/kmem", O_RDONLY);

    if (fd < 0)
    {
        perror("open /dev/kmem failed");
        return -1;
    }

    unsigned long page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);

    unsigned long page_aligned_offset = (start_address/page_size)*page_size;
    unsigned long area_pages = area_len/page_size + (area_len%page_size ? 1 : 0);

    kernel_mem =
        mmap(0, area_pages,
           PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED,
           fd, page_aligned_offset);

    if (kernel_mem == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        perror("mmap failed");

        return -1;
    }

    if (!mlock((const void*)kernel_mem,area_len))
    {
        perror("mlock failed");

        return -1;
    }

    unsigned long offset_into_page = start_address-page_aligned_offset;
    unsigned long start_area_address = (unsigned long)kernel_mem + offset_into_page;
    unsigned long end_area_address = start_area_address+area_len-pattern_len+1;

    unsigned long addr;

    setup_segv_handler();

    for (addr = start_area_address; addr < end_area_address;addr++)
    {
        unsigned char* kmp = (unsigned char*)addr;
        unsigned char* pmp = (unsigned char*)pattern;
        size_t index = 0;
        for (index = 0; index < pattern_len; index++)
        {
            if (setjmp(restore_point) == 0)
            {
                unsigned char p = *pmp;
                unsigned char k = *kmp;

                if (k != p)
                {
                    break;
                }

                pmp++;
                kmp++;
            }
            else
            {
                addr += page_size -1;

                setup_segv_handler();
                break;
            }
        }

        if (index >= pattern_len)
        {
            return addr;
        }
    }

    munmap(kernel_mem,area_pages);

    close(fd);

    return 0;
 }
```

I realize I can use functions like memcmp to avoid programming the matching part directly (I did this initially), but I subsequently wanted to insure the finest grained control for recovering from the faults so I could see exactly what was happening.
I scoured the Internet to find information about this behavior, and came up empty.  The linux system I am running this under is arm 3.12.30.
If what I am trying to do is not possible under linux, is there some way I can get the current state of the kernel pages from user space (which would allow me to avoid trying to search pages that are inaccessible.)  I searched for calls that might provide such information, but also came up empty.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried to use `sigsetjmp`/`siglongjmp` instead of `setjmp`/`longjmp`? This pair seems to be more suitable for signal handlers, as it also restores signal mask, which could be changed when signal handler is called.

Comment: That did the trick.  Thanks very much for the help!.  BTW, I am a stackoverflow noob, so I could see no way to tag this as an "accepted" answer.  Let me know what I need to do.

Comment: These are the **comments**, They are used for requesting additional info about the problem, ... or for check some *guesses*. Because comments are not necessary contain a resolution of the problem, they cannot be accepted. I have added a real **answer**, which you may accept if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `longjmp` is perfectly allowed to be used in the signal handler (the function is known as *async-signal-safe*, see [man signal-safety](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)) and effectively exits from the signal handling, it doesn't restore signal mask. The mask is automatically modified at the time when signal handler is called to block new *SIGSEGV* signal to interrupt the handler.

While one may restore signal mask manually, it is better (and simpler) to use `siglongjmp` function instead: aside from the effect of `longjmp`, it also restores the signal mask. Of course, in that case `sigsetjmp` function should be used instead of `setjmp`:

```
// ... in main() function
if(sigsetjmp(restore_point, 1)) // Aside from other things, store signal mask
// ...

// ... in the signal handler
siglongjmp(restore_point); // Also restore signal mask as it was at sigsetjmp() call
```